# A Docker container for each MySQL install

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-swarm

I'm looking to move the databases for my Wordpress sites to their own serve. My question is, for each site, should I run a separate docker container with it's own MySQL install, or is that overkill?

In my head it makes sense, but I was hoping someone has done this in the real-world.

Comment: Personally, I'd rather run a single larger non-Dockerized instance/cluster for the databases.

Comment: One thing that may be a factor is that these are small sites.

Comment: A few hundred small, low-traffic WordPress sites likely won't bother a $50/month MySQL instance.

Comment: There are pros and cons to either, but a single MySQL serving lots of little sites is likely way more efficient on resources. Doing the "consolidated SQL" route does mean that it becomes a single point of failure, so make sure you do SQL replication and high-availability if you need it.